# MVC 3 - checkbox send value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to prepare two checkbox. First checkbox will always have value true and always be checked, but I do not know how to do it.

[image]

In second checkbox, if customer will agree this checkbox will send me some values. This is my example, but doesn't work correct.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SaleAgree)
@{
    ViewData["SaleAgree"] = true;  
}
```

Comment: http://translate.google.com/ (If it's not clear enough, I can't even understand the question and that code snipet makes no sense at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First checkbox will always have value true:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.SaleAgree, new { @checked="checked" })
```

Second checkbox If customer will agree this checkbox will send me some values:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.SecondProperty, new { id="second" })
```

and then `jquery`: http://jsfiddle.net/X2RtY/ (on change event you can make request with `$.ajax`)